# Get all of the values from one column in Excel using office script

Tags: typescript

```
{let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet(Sheet1)
selectedSheet.getRange("F:F").insert(ExcelScript.InsertShiftDirection.right);
selectedSh`your text`eet.getRange("F:F").copyFrom(selectedSheet.getRange("E:E"));
selectedSheet.getRange("$F:$F").removeDuplicates([0], false);}
```

I need to get the values of the column F after removing the duplicate value in them. In the last line, I already removed the duplicates in column F. How can I get all the values in column f? When I try to get it as get usedrange.getvalue I am getting only the first line. Can someone help me to get all the values in the column F?

Comment: Use ```getValues()``` on the range of column F, like ```let values = selectedSheet.getRange("F:F").getValues();```

Comment: when i try this code i get the value as Null.which is not the actual values in the column

Answer (score 0):

```
let selectedSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
let columnFRange = selectedSheet.getRange("F:F");
let values = columnFRange.getValues();
```

`values` is a 2D array where each inner array represents a row in the range. To get the values from column `F`, you can loop over the rows and select the value from the fifth column (since js arrays are 0-indexed, the fifth column corresponds to index 4):

```
let columnFValues: any[] = values.map(row => row[4]);
```

`columnFValues` is an array containing all the values from column `F`.

**Note that if the last cells in column F are empty, they will be included in `columnFValues` as `undefined`*.

If you want to exclude these, you can filter them out by doing;

```
columnFValues = columnFValues.filter(value => value !== undefined);
```